# bootstrap 5 does not throw the show.bs.dropdown and hide.bs.dropdown events

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm making a website on a bundle of webpack4+bootstrap 5, I need to add animation to dropdown in the menu. On the Internet, they advise to do this:

```
     $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
       $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });

    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
```

But for some reason, the events are not intercepted. The HTML code is as follows:

```
. . .
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link menu_level_1 dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href=""
    id="nav_link_3" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    Каталог
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="nav_link_3">
    . . .
  </ul>
</li>
. . .
```

Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, but I also tried querySelectorAll / addEventListener - the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

The events are triggered by the toggle element, not the dropdown parent element..,

```
var theDropdown = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuLink')
theDropdown.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     alert('hi');
})

theDropdown.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
     alert('bye');
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/mbImPQWhI4

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just understood from the description that the event needs to be bound to the parent object. It turns out that this is not the case

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle').forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
        })

        el.addEventListener('hide.bs.dropdown', function (ev) {
            $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
        })
    })
})